# Given Two line segments and endpoints, return configurations where segments share endpoint

Tags: c++, rotation, eigen, rotational-matrices

I'm stuck on a problem where we're given the starting position (P0) and length (L0) of one line segment and the starting position (P1) and length (L1) of another line segment, and we return the configurations where both segments end at the same point. I'm coding a function in C++ that returns one valid configuration for such inputs, or indicates that no configuration is valid. Below are the files that I made, which utilize the Eigen C++ libraries.

SegmentConfigurations.cpp

```
 /* SegmentConfigurations.cpp : Defines a utility function that calculates the
  * orientation for two input line segments such that they share a common
  * endpoint, and the other endpoints are specified as inputs.
  * Details on the implementation are described in the write-up document.
  */

#include "RotationMatrix.h"
#include "SegmentConfigurations.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

// calculate the square of the number "x"
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
// calculate the magnitude of the vector with coordinates (x,y,z)
#define magnitude(x,y,z) (sqrt((x)*(x) + (y)*(y) + (z)*(z)))

/* Returns a configuration such that the two input line segments share
 * a common point (see previous explanation).
 *
 * Parameters:
 * p0, p1: Two input points.
 * l0: The length of the line segment that includes p0 as one endpoint.
 * l1: The length of the line segment that includes p1 as one endpoint.
 *     Function assumes l0 and l1 are both non-negative.
 *
 * Output:
 * An Orientation structure containing two non-null 3x3 rotation matrices
 * specifying the orientations for the line segments, or NULL if there is
 * no configuration that allows the two line segments to share an endpoint.
 */
struct Orientations *segment_configurations(Vector3d p0, double l0,
                                            Vector3d p1, double l1)
{
    // vector pointing in the direction from p0 to p1
    Vector3d vector_p0_to_p1 = p1 - p0;
    // distance from p0 to p1
    double p0_p1_dist = vector_p0_to_p1.norm();
    if (l0 + l1 < p0_p1_dist || p0_p1_dist < fabs(l0 - l1))
        return NULL; // no solution possible

    struct Orientations *result = (struct Orientations*)calloc(1,
                                   sizeof(struct Orientations));

    Vector3d circle_center = p0; // center is p0 if points are the same
    if (!p0_p1_dist) // p0_p1_dist == 0
    {
        result->rotation1 = Matrix3d::Identity();
        result->rotation2 = Matrix3d::Identity();
        return result;
    }
    double d0 = (l0*l0 - l1*l1 + square(p0_p1_dist)) / (2 * p0_p1_dist);
    double radius_of_circle = sqrt(l0*l0 - d0*d0);
    // scale vector from p0 to p1 so it has length d0
    vector_p0_to_p1 = vector_p0_to_p1 * d0 / p0_p1_dist;
    // final calculation to find center of circle
    circle_center = vector_p0_to_p1 + circle_center;
    printf("circle center: %f, %f, %f\n\n", circle_center[0], circle_center[1], circle_center[2]);
    if (!radius_of_circle)
    {
        if (!l0) // l0 == 0
        {
            result->rotation1 = Matrix3d::Identity();
            result->rotation2 = rotation_matrix(Vector3d::UnitX(), vector_p0_to_p1);
            return result;
        }
        result->rotation1 = rotation_matrix(Vector3d::UnitX(), vector_p0_to_p1);
        result->rotation2 = Matrix3d::Identity();
        return result;
    }

    // Note: vector_p0_to_p1 is perpendicular to circle

    Vector3d center_to_elbow(0, 0, -1);
    if (vector_p0_to_p1[2])
    {
        Vector3d center_to_point( 1, 0, 0 );
        if (vector_p0_to_p1[0] && vector_p0_to_p1[1])
        {
            // ratio of y-component of circle normal vector to its x-component
            double normal_y_x_ratio = vector_p0_to_p1[1] / vector_p0_to_p1[0];
            center_to_point[0] = radius_of_circle*sqrt(1 / (square(normal_y_x_ratio) + 1));
            center_to_point[1] = (-vector_p0_to_p1[0] * center_to_point[0]) / vector_p0_to_p1[1];
            center_to_elbow = vector_p0_to_p1.cross(center_to_point);
        }
        else if (vector_p0_to_p1[0])
        {
            // we know that vector_p0_to_p1[1] == 0
            center_to_point[0] = 0;
            center_to_point[1] = 1;
            center_to_elbow = vector_p0_to_p1.cross(center_to_point);
        }
        else if (vector_p0_to_p1[1])
        {
            // we know that vector_p0_to_p1[0] == 0
            center_to_elbow = vector_p0_to_p1.cross(center_to_point);
        }
        else
        {
            center_to_elbow[0] = 1;
            center_to_elbow[1] = 0;
            center_to_elbow[2] = 0;
        }
        // otherwise, use default value for point
    }
    // otherwise, use default value for elbow
    /* Ensures that center_to_elbow has non-positive z-value and
     * magnitude equal to "radius".
     */
    if (center_to_elbow[2] > 0)
        center_to_elbow = center_to_elbow * (-radius_of_circle / center_to_elbow.norm());
    else
        center_to_elbow = center_to_elbow * (radius_of_circle / center_to_elbow.norm());
    // get point on circumference with lowest z-value; call this the "elbow"
    printf("cte: %f, %f, %f\n\n", center_to_elbow[0], center_to_elbow[1], center_to_elbow[2]);

        Vector3d elbow_point = circle_center + center_to_elbow;
        Vector3d p0_to_elbow = elbow_point - p0;
        Vector3d elbow_to_p1 = p1 - elbow_point;
        printf("elbow: %f, %f, %f\n\n", elbow_point[0], elbow_point[1], elbow_point[2]);
        printf("p0te: %f, %f, %f\n\n", p0_to_elbow[0], p0_to_elbow[1], p0_to_elbow[2]);
        printf("length: %f\n\n", p0_to_elbow.norm());
        printf("etp1: %f, %f, %f\n\n", elbow_to_p1[0], elbow_to_p1[1], elbow_to_p1[2]);
        printf("length: %f\n\n", elbow_to_p1.norm());

        result->rotation1 = rotation_matrix(Vector3d::UnitX(), p0_to_elbow);
        result->rotation2 = rotation_matrix(p0_to_elbow, elbow_to_p1);

        return result;
    }


    int main()

{
    double inputs[5][8] = { {1,5,2,3,4,5,6,4}, {1,2,5,3,4,6,5,4}, {2,1,2,5,15,1,2,12}, {5,-1,-7,15,-10,-9,-7,8}, {2,4,-1,7,-5,28,-1,24} };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        double *values = inputs[i];
        Vector3d p0(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
        Vector3d p1(values[4], values[5], values[6]);
        printf("point 1: %f,%f,%f,%f\n\n", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
        printf("point 2: %f,%f,%f,%f\n\n", values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7]);
        Vector3d diff = p1 - p0;
        printf("diff: %f,%f,%f\n\n", diff[0], diff[1], diff[2]);

        struct Orientations *output = segment_configurations(p0, values[3], p1, values[7]);
        if (output != NULL)
        {
            Matrix3d rotation1 = output->rotation1;
            Matrix3d rotation2 = output->rotation2;
            printf("Rotation 1:\n\n");
            print_three_by_three(output->rotation1);
            printf("Rotation 2:\n\n");
            print_three_by_three(output->rotation2);
            Matrix4d R_01 = rotation_to_homogeneous(output->rotation1);
            Matrix4d T_12 = translation(values[3], 0, 0);
            Matrix4d R_23 = rotation_to_homogeneous(output->rotation2);
            Matrix4d T_34 = translation(values[7], 0, 0);
            printf("R01:\n\n");
            print_four_by_four(R_01);
            printf("T12:\n\n");
            print_four_by_four(T_12);
            printf("R23:\n\n");
            print_four_by_four(R_23);
            printf("T34:\n\n");
            print_four_by_four(T_34);

            // Goal is to see if rotation and translation matrices together reach p1 from p0.
            Matrix4d M1 = R_01 * T_12;
            Matrix4d M2 = R_23 * M1;
            Matrix4d M3 = M2 * T_34;
            printf("M1:\n\n");
            print_four_by_four(M1);
            printf("M2:\n\n");
            print_four_by_four(M2);
            printf("M3:\n\n");
            print_four_by_four(M3);

            Vector3d M1_disp(M1(0, 3), M1(1, 3), M1(2, 3));
            Vector3d elbow = p0 + M1_disp;
            printf("calc Elbow:  %f,%f,%f\n\n", elbow[0], elbow[1], elbow[2]);
            Vector3d p0toelbow = elbow - p0;
            printf("calc p0toe:  %f,%f,%f\n\n", p0toelbow[0], p0toelbow[1], p0toelbow[2]);
            Vector3d calc_elbowtop1 = output->rotation2 * p0toelbow;
            printf("calc etop1:  %f,%f,%f\n\n", calc_elbowtop1[0], calc_elbowtop1[1], calc_elbowtop1[2]);

            Vector3d M3_disp(M3(0, 3), M3(1, 3), M3(2, 3));
            Vector3d endeffector = p0 + M3_disp;
            printf("result:  %f,%f,%f\n", endeffector[0], endeffector[1], endeffector[2]);
        }
        else
            printf("No answer!\n");
        printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

SegmentConfigurations.h

```
// SegmentConfigurations.h

#include <Eigen\Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

/* Stores two 3x3 rotation matrices that orient the two line segments given as
* input to the function "segment_configurations" (see previous explanation).
*/
struct Orientations
{
    Matrix3d rotation1;
    Matrix3d rotation2;
};
```

RotationMatrix.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Eigen\Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

void print_three_by_three(Matrix3d M)
{
    printf("[ %f  %f  %f\n\n", M(0,0), M(0,1), M(0,2));
    printf("  %f  %f  %f\n\n", M(1,0), M(1,1), M(1,2));
    printf("  %f  %f  %f ]\n\n", M(2,0), M(2,1), M(2,2));
}

void print_four_by_four(Matrix4d M)
{
    printf("[ %f  %f  %f  %f\n\n", M(0, 0), M(0, 1), M(0, 2), M(0,3));
    printf("  %f  %f  %f  %f\n\n", M(1, 0), M(1, 1), M(1, 2), M(1,3));
    printf("  %f  %f  %f  %f\n\n", M(2, 0), M(2, 1), M(2, 2), M(2,3));
    printf("  %f  %f  %f  %f]\n\n",  M(3, 0), M(3, 1), M(3, 2), M(3,3));
}

// change 3x3 rotation matrix into 4x4 homogeneous matrix representing same rotation
Matrix4d rotation_to_homogeneous(Matrix3d M)
{
    Matrix4d result;
    result << M(0, 0), M(0, 1), M(0, 2), 0,
              M(1, 0), M(1, 1), M(1, 2), 0,
              M(2, 0), M(2, 1), M(2, 2), 0,
              0, 0, 0, 1;
    return result;
}

// create 4x4 homogeneous matrix representing translation by amount (x,y,z)
Matrix4d translation(double x, double y, double z)
{
    Matrix4d result;
    result << 1, 0, 0, x,
              0, 1, 0, y,
              0, 0, 1, z,
              0, 0, 0, 1;
    return result;
}

/* Return a 3x3 rotation matrix, representing a rotation in 3-dimensions
* from vector0 to vector1. The matrix is calculated using the equation
* in the Wikipedia article for "Rotation matrices" under the section
* titled "Rotation matrix from axis and angle" (link to article below).
* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
*
* Parameters:
* vector0, vector1: The input vectors for which the 3-dimensional
*     rotation is calculated.
*
* Output:
* A 3x3 rotation matrix that represents how to rotate vector0
*     in order to produce vector1.
*/
Matrix3d rotation_matrix(Vector3d vector0, Vector3d vector1)
{
    printf("in function\n");
    printf("p0te: %f, %f, %f\n\n", vector0[0], vector0[1], vector0[2]);
    printf("etp1: %f, %f, %f\n\n", vector1[0], vector1[1], vector1[2]);
    vector0.normalize();
    vector1.normalize();
    printf("normalize\n");
    printf("p0te: %f, %f, %f\n\n", vector0[0], vector0[1], vector0[2]);
    printf("etp1: %f, %f, %f\n\n", vector1[0], vector1[1], vector1[2]);
    // vector orthogonal to both inputs
    Vector3d u = vector0.cross(vector1);
    if (!u.norm())
    {
        if (vector0 == vector1)
            return Matrix3d::Identity();
        // return rotation matrix that represents 180 degree rotation
        Matrix3d m1;
        m1 << -1, 0, 0,
               0,-1, 0,
               0, 0, 1;
        return m1;
    }

    /* For the angle between both inputs:
     * 1) The sine is the magnitude of their cross product.
     * 2) The cosine equals their dot product.
     */
    // sine must be calculated using original cross product
    printf("u: %f, %f, %f\n\n", u[0], u[1], u[2]);
    double sine = u.norm();
    double cosine = vector0.dot(vector1);
    printf("sine: %f\n\n", sine);
    printf("cosine: %f\n\n", cosine);
    u.normalize();
    printf("u (norm'd): %f, %f, %f\n\n", u[0], u[1], u[2]);

    Matrix3d tensor_product_matrix;
    double ux = u[0];
    double uy = u[1];
    double uz = u[2];
    tensor_product_matrix << ux*ux, ux*uy, ux*uz,
                             ux*uy, uy*uy, uy*uz,
                             ux*uz, uy*uz, uz*uz;
    Matrix3d cross_product_matrix;
    cross_product_matrix << 0, -uz, uy,
                            uz,   0,-ux,
                           -uy,  ux,  0;


    Matrix3d part1 = Matrix3d::Identity();
    Matrix3d part2 = cross_product_matrix * sine;
    Matrix3d part3 = cross_product_matrix*cross_product_matrix * (1 - cosine);
    return part1 + part2 + part3;
}
```

SegmentConfigurations.cpp includes tests in the main function for visually checking that the orientations are correct. The idea is that the function "M3" is a homogeneous transformation matrix from the base frame to the the frame of the end-effector (whose origin is P1). The hope is that the displacement factor of this matrix added to P0 would result in P1, but that isn't always the case because "M3" isn't correct, or at least I think. I'm not sure if part of my function is wrong, or if I'm testing it wrong, and this is the main part of where I'm stuck. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: This looks like overkill. Anyway, what makes you think that this code doesn't work? What makes you think that your **M3** is incorrect? What arguments do you give this code (two points and two lengths) that cause it to give you results that you think are wrong, and what do you think the right results are, and why?

Comment: One of the failed inputs is P0 = <1,2,5>, L0 = 3, P1 = <4,6,5>, L1 = 4. The resulting M3 has the translation factor as <3.36, 4.48, 4.2>. I think this is wrong because this added to P0 does not result in P1. Also, I tried a slightly different version of the code where "M2 = M1 * R_23", and the translation factor there was <4.8432, 1.751718, -3.719529>.